# Загрузчик Window / Linux

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, linux-mint, dual-boot

Купил новый ноутбук с установленной Windows 10. Решил как обычно установить рядом Linux Mint, закачал на флешку, выполнил установку, всё ок. Первые 1-2 перезагрузки компьютера нормально спрашивало меня какую систему загружать, но после всегда стала грузится Windows. Если жать при включении <kbd>F8</kbd>, то первые 2 варианта следующие: Ubuntu и Windows boot manager, при выборе Ubuntu всё равно грузится Windows.
Что бы посоветовали?

Comment: А загрузчик на grub не меняли во время установки минта? Попробуйте зажать shift при загрузке

Comment: Ничего вообще не менял. Просто установил линукс и все. Долбил по shift как бешеный, но ничего